# iOS Wifi Camera Box EAAccessory Connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, ip-camera, eaaccessory

I have a Wifi Box connected to a camera via a cable. The iPhone is connected to this boxes wifi. In the suggested (pre built) iOS app it connects and displays the feed.

How do I connect to the device inside my own app.(Objective c)

I have setup EAAccessory with the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_accessoryDidConnect:) name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification object:nil];
```

However this is never triggered.

I then search for all connected accessories

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]];
```

and

```
EAAccessoryManager* accessoryManager = [
                                        EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager];
if (accessoryManager)
{
    NSArray* connectedAccessories =
    [accessoryManager connectedAccessories];
    if (connectedAccessories.count > 0) {
        LoggerApp(1, @"ConnectedAccessories");
    }
}
```

Still no luck.

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated, Thank you

Comment: I also am struggling with this